# My activity_main.xml still uses the default theme even after I specified another theme

Tags: android, android-theme

My activity_main.xml still uses the default theme even after I specified another theme. Please find my code below:

**styles**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Launch screen -->
    <style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

**manifest**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  ...
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_orange"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Even though I've set the `LaunchScreenTheme` above, it still uses the default `AppTheme`

Any idea why?

Comment: try with style `style="@style/AppTheme"` instead of theme. if you want to use theme then specify it in manifest to `<activity>` inline

Comment: In the manifest file? I still want `AppTheme` to be the default but I want activity_main.xml to use `LaunchScreenTheme`

Comment: in manifest I am telling to set theme to perfect activity not the application tag.

Comment: if you want to use in xml then specify it as style

Comment: Just tried settings `style="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"` in the xml file. It doesn't work - still uses the default `AppTheme`

Comment: try clean and build.

Comment: did you tried setting theme to activity `<activity
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">` like below

Comment: Yes I tried changing the manifest to `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">` and it still uses `AppTheme`

Comment: remove theme from application and set it individually to activities. it should work

Comment: I removed the application theme and it still uses `AppTheme`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185283/discussion-between-karan-mer-and-zorgan).

Answer (score 1):

In `activity_main.xml`, try `style:"@style/LaunchScreenTheme"` instead `android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set a theme specifically for an activity then you have set it like this in your manifest -

```
<activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme" />
```

if you want to set a theme for the whole application then you have to set it like this is your manifest -

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">
```

...

Comment: I have done exactly that (set the individual activity theme to `android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"`, and set the whole application theme to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`) however it still shows `AppTheme` for my individual activity. Any idea?

Comment: set your application theme into `android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"`
then make another style for your desired activity it will work.

and your custom style should be like this  -
`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`